# Gathering dynamic text from div and passing it on through querystring

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've downloaded this template which is basically a web room chat for Tornado in python: https://github.com/nellessen/Tornado-Redis-Chat

I'm attempting to get all the messages from the "messsages" div and pass it on through a querystring as the variable 'msgs'. *The reason I'm using querystring is because the POST function can't be implemented in the github project and I can't pass data through JSON chunks as I have no clue on how to even begin.* Once the msgs is passed on querystring, through PHP means, I'm able to echo the messages on a page called 'message log'.

I've attempted the following:

```
var msgs = document.getElementById("messsages").innerHTML
```

but that just gets everything including the div ids, styles etc. rather than just the text content. And when I have tried .textContent or .text, on the message log page, I either get a blank page or a page showing "undefined". I think the issue of "undefined" may be because the variable msgs is not updating its value to the messages being posted on the messsages div.

Any suggestions?

**JS THAT TRIGGERS THE MESSAGES TO BE VIEWED ON PAGE**

```
showMessage = function(message) {
    console.log("Show Message");
    var existing = $("#m" + message._id);
    if (existing.length > 0) return;
    $("#messsages").append('<div class="message" id="' + message._id + '">' + message.body + '</div>');
    $('#messsages').find(".message:last").slideDown("fast", function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 400);
    });
};
```

Comment: Just wondering why you tagged php instead of python? (edit: nvm, read over it)

Answer (score 1):

you cant use id of `#messages` if there are multiple `<div>` messages you want to get the text from. instead, use class `.messages`

since you tagged jQuery, im assuming youre open to using it, and `.each()` is a function that loops through each of the selector elements so something like this:

```
var msgs = []; // initialize array
$('.messages').each(function() {
    msgs.push($(this).text()); // add the text in this specific message div into the array
});
```

if you want just one long string, then construct a string instead of an array.

Comment: Hey, the result when i enter the variable 'msgs' in my console is [ ]. And there is also a blank page on message log. This refers to the issue that perhaps the variable is not updating to register the new value of the messages div. The first thing that comes to mind is .onchange but that only works for inputs.

Comment: OP's main problem is updating the msgs variable everytime a message is posted. I'm assuming that @KingAlfredChameleon originally, your messages div is blank, hence why you are getting a blank result in your console. Then you post a message and check in your console if any change has been made to the value of the msgs variable.

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon, you want to activate this code whenever the new messages div hits the dom, so whatever event triggers the messages to "get placed in the view" is the one you put this code into.

Comment: @indubitablee Could this be what you're talking about?  `showMessage = function(message) {
    console.log("Show Message");
    var existing = $("#m" + message._id);
    if (existing.length > 0) return;
    $("#messsages").append('<div class="message" id="' + message._id + '">' + message.body + '</div>');
    $('#messsages').find(".message:last").slideDown("fast", function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 400);
    });
};`    If so, I'm not sure of the code on how I would update the msgs variable on this JS event.

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon I suggest adding that code to the original question!

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon yes, thats the function that puts the message on the dom, now at the end of that function, add my whole code in with a `console.log(msgs);` at the end

Comment: @indubitablee this is what comes up on the console:  ["↵↵"] for #messsages  and [ ] for .message

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon are there any errors that show up in the console as well? its hard to diagnose what the problem is further without seeing all the relevant code and how it interacts...

Comment: No, would you be willing to join.me or teamviewer me to see it all for yourself?

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon Sorry, i cannot at this time, but i'll whip up an example to try and help

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon ahaha, you put my code after the function, put it inside the function `showMessage`. put line 107-111 after line 105 and inside the last `};` (line 106) of the function. let me know if that works.

Comment: @indubitablee oh! Now I receive "msgs is not defined"

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon alright, lemme try to whip something up

Comment: @KingAlfredChameleon check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/197/ and modify according to your needs

Comment: Hey, I've modified the code, do I replace the function I showed you earlier with it?